# Converting string to num with a specific format in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, formatting, numeric

```
>> str = '0009.51998'
>> str2num(str)
```

or

```
>> sscanf(str,'%f')

ans = 9.5200
```

I want to get this instead:

```
ans = 9.51998
```

Comment: if you already have a string, why are you suing num2str? (I realize this doesn't change your question/answer it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that. It's just being rounded off to four decimal places when it's displayed. Do `format long` to see more precision.

```
>> str = '0009.51998';
>> x = sscanf(str, '%f')
x =
    9.5200
>> format long
>> x
x =
   9.519980000000000
>>
```

You can also use `str2double` as an alternative to `sscanf`. It's safer and more flexible than `str2num`. That is because `str2num` uses the `eval` command. For example, try the following:

```
  str2num(' figure();imshow(''peppers.png'')')
```

You might be surprised at the results.